# why does floor return in this example one element less

Tags: r, floor

I am running `R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"` and there should be something that I am missing with respect to the `floor` function since I would expect the latest integer to be `25` in the following example:

```
a = 50.8
b = 25.9
floor(a:b)
```

Note however that the following works as expected:

```
c = 10.96
d = 9.3
floor(c:d)
c = 10.96
d = 9.9
floor(c:d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't understand `:`. The documentation says

> For other arguments `from:to` is equivalent to `seq(from, to)`, and
>   generates a sequence from `from` to `to` in steps of 1 or -1.

The last value that can be reached from 50.8 by subtracting multiples of 1 without surpassing 25.9 is 26.8. And `floor(26.8)` is 26.